# Defining a variable when I define a mysql function

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I get an error when defining the following mysql function:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION PDATE(`gdate` datetime) RETURNS char(100) CHARSET utf8
BEGIN
    DECLARE 
        i,
        gy, gm, gd,
        g_day_no, j_day_no, j_np,
        jy, jm, jd INT DEFAULT 0;
END
```

The error is:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
> corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
> near '' at line 11

Even if I simply define just one variable, I get this error.
What is the problem?

Thanks...

Comment: Did you set delimiters? And I suppose you have a return statement in your actual code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You code is multi statement so you might need to set delimiters https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/stored-programs-defining.html and 'the function body must contain a RETURN value statement' - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-procedure.html

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS F;

DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION F(`gdate` datetime) 
RETURNS char(100) CHARSET utf8
BEGIN
    DECLARE 
        i,
        gy, gm, gd,
        g_day_no, j_day_no, j_np,
        jy, jm, jd 
          INT DEFAULT 0;
     RETURN i;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8kWMQjBS57kNaAKWq2EZhM/1

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is your function needs to do something in addition to DECLARE.

I would not recommend to use uppercase for object names

```sql
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS pdate ;
DELIMITER //
CREATE FUNCTION pdate(gdate DATETIME)
RETURNS VARCHAR(100) CHARSET UTF8
BEGIN
  DECLARE i, gy, gm, gd, g_day_no, j_np, jy, jm, jd INT DEFAULT 0 ;
  DECLARE r_value VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT NULL ;
  SET r_value:=DAYOFWEEK(gdate) ; -- for example
  RETURN r_value ;
END//
DELIMITER ;
```